# How can i change the Package family name in uwp windows 10

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, release-management

I want to change the key mentioned in fig., when i change the certificate file it changes to the another temporary key, and the publisher folder is creating with this key as name. but i want it as a meaningful name. is it possible.? 
if anybody knows, please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Together, these elements declare the identity of your app, establishing the "package family" to which all of its packages belong. Individual packages will have additional details, such as architecture and version.

[image]

The package family name is the combination of `YourProjectName` and `TemporaryKey`. And the `Temporaraykey` is a hash value of the `Publisher`. PFN(Package family name) gets automatically populated as a combination of `Package name` and the `Temporarykey`. It just changes with the value of `Publisher` changing. But it will always be a hash value not a meaningful name.

Comment: Also while installing my app, Since i have specified publisher cache folder it will create a folder inside publisher folder (ie. ..\AppData\Local\Publishers\53xf6sf2p7nwp) and the folder name matches the temporary key. is there any way to create that folder with a meaningful name instead of creating it with the temporary key.

Comment: You could not change the publisher cache folder name. It is unique name match your temporary key. But you could specify the folder name inside `53xf6sf2p7nwp` folder by following code writed in your app manifest `Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.publisherCacheFolders">
      <PublisherCacheFolders>
        <Folder Name="TestFolder" />
      </PublisherCacheFolders>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions> `.

Comment: Yeah,i have some folders inside the publisher cache folder and i can give names to that folders as you mentioned, but my actual intention is to change the publisher cache folder name to a meaningful name. Anyway thanks for your update.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT if I know Package name and publisher, is it possible for me to guess PFN?? If yes, is there any documentation how to do that??