# Schedule background app

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, windows-task-scheduler

So I have my application deployed to my Raspberry Pi 3 that is running win10 IoT, and I want to use schtasks to run it at certain times. Where is my application "deployed" to on the device so I can add it to a scheduled task?

Edit:
Found the app, but I can't seem to create a scheduled task to run the .winmd file.

This is what I tried:

```
schtasks /create /tn feedertest /sc minute /ru administrator /rp notrealpwd /mo 5 /tr "c:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\CatFeeders-uwpVS.Debug_ARM.greg\catfeeders.winmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

***WINMD*** file is not an executable file for running the UWP application, it is a binary file of Windows Runtime Metadata.
You need to use [IotStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/commandlineutils#setting-startup-app) command to run the UWP application on Windows IoT Core. Please refer to following command:

Update:

```
#create the task
schtasks /create /tn feedertest /sc minute /ru administrator /rp notrealpwd /mo 1 /tr "IotStartup add headed <your app package family name>"

#run the task
schtasks /Run /TN feedertest
```

BTW, you can get how to get app package family name from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316752/how-can-i-change-the-package-family-name-in-uwp-windows-10).

Comment: That got me closer! It still wouldn't run, so I tried from the command line and now I am getting this:

`PS C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Documents> IotStartup run CatFeeders-uwp_f3hfmmwf56e24
ERROR: failed to activate CatFeeders-uwp_f3hfmmwf56e24!App (0x80070005)`

That code is "access denied", yes I'm connected to it with powershell in administrator mode (no UAC), but test running the scheduled task doesn't work either

Comment: You can try to use the following cmdlet:`iotstartup add headed <app identity>`. It can active the headed application in powershell.

Comment: I don't want it to start on startup though, I need to be able to run it through schtasks

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT can this be used to run a UWP app as Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, but it looks like Windows IoT isn't the right platform for what I'm trying to do. :( 
I switched Raspbian, wrote about 20 lines of python, and added it to the crontab.