# Get-AppxPackage unique value when application is updated

Tags: powershell, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, appx

Im collecting a list of Windows Store Applications.
Im using this powershell script :

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

This gives me back multiple applications.

I want to know if there is a unique value for an application that stays the same when the application is updated!

This is an example from one application with its values.
[image: This is an example from one application with its values.]

Comment: The `PackageFamilyName` is unique.

Comment: @kennyzx , If i have 2 the same applications, x64 and x86. The PackageFamilyName is the same.

Comment: Look at the `PackageFullName`, it consists of 4 parts. The second part is the version of the package which will change in upgrade while the other 3 parts stay the same. You can use a combination of the 1st+3rd+4th part, which is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who are looking for an answer, Kenny named the solution.

I quote :

Look at the `PackageFullName`, it consists of 4 parts. The second part is the version of the package which will change in upgrade while the other 3 parts stay the same. You can use a combination of the 1st+3rd+4th part, which is unique

What is the [PackageFamilyName (PFN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316752/how-can-i-change-the-package-family-name-in-uwp-windows-10)?

> If i have 2 the same applications, x64 and x86. The PackageFamilyName is the same.

That is correct, because it is the same app, but built for different architectures.